# How to render a page content with dynamic routing on page reload?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a SPA with dynamic routing. On page loading I'm making a fetch request for products. Then set it to the vuex store and use it. I also have a dynamic routing for product pages `'/product/:id'`

The problem is if I reload a product page say `site.com/product/2` then nothing renders. I think this happens because at that moment store is empty and there're nothing to render.

How can I fix that?

In ProductPage component I tried using navigation guard with no success. Code below returns error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')`.

Fetch request is made on mounting in TheMain component (when I reload ProductPage fetch request is made as well).

ProductPage component:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["products"]), // get products array from store
  },

  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (this.products) { // check if products array exists and then load data
      next(true);
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make `beforeRouteEnter` async and add `await` for the store action which does the fetch or axios call.

```
async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (this.products) { 
       // check if products array exists and then load data
       await dispatch(‘action_to_get_data’);
       /// Wait to go to next for dispatch to finish. 
       next(true);
    }
}
```

In your action you also need to use async / await.

What also might help is a `v-if` on the ProductPage component, so the components only loads when the products are loaded in the store.

For vue3 you may also take a look at the experimental Suspense component. But I don’t know if this works with beforeRouteEnter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I fetch the data in Main component on mounting. Should I make two identical requests then?

Comment: The `beforeRouteEnter` runs always on the load of a page, doesn’t it? So you would not need the call the action in that component.

Comment: What also might work,  if your Main component is the parent of the ProductPage in the router (with `router-view` In the main) that you call the action before the Main component loads and with `v-if` load the `router-view` when the products are in the store.